# LED on RS485 bus

Tags: led, rs485

I would like to insert two LEDs on an RS485 bus (i.e. on the RX and TX side) that flash when there is a communication passage.

I have a 24V power supply, and I could use op-amps (like the LM358) or some BJTs (NPN and PNP).

Would it be OK to use amplifiers in buffer mode or a PNP BJT?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1KHsj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXDAYP.png)</sup>

Comment: You can just do LED + series resistor to ground, straight from the data lines. The transceivers will have no problem driving the LED as long as you use some sensible current level, <5mA or so. What kind of LEDs are these, regular SMD 0603/0805 or so?

Comment: 485 is differential so, do you mean the RX and TX lines as produced by an interface chip? Be absolutely unambiguous about this.

Comment: @Lundin I have already tried a similar solution, but the LEDs do not light up in any way (to be on the safe side, I even reversed their polarity to no avail). The LEDs are simple through-hole components.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, they are produced by an interface chip: communication starts from a microcontroller and then passes through a transceiver for RS-485, i.e. a MAX1487.

Comment: @Alinik in your BJT circuit above you picked 24mA, which is too much and possibly outside the spec of the average through-hole LED. 20mA is what they usually rate them for, but in practice one drives them with <5mA. Hmm btw shouldnt that be a NPN?

Comment: Ach wait isn't the RS485 spec saying some +/- 1.5V? You need something with higher voltage then the LED forward voltage to drive it, obviously.

Comment: @Alinik I don't think you've answered Andy's question. He already knows how RS485 works, but is asking you which side of the interface chip you're planning to connect to - the separated single-ended RX & TX lines on the microcontroller side, or the combined differential A/B lines on the RS485 bus side?

Comment: @brhans Thank you for making me realise that I was not clear in my previous answer to Andy. I am referring to the combined differential A/B lines on the RS485 bus side.

Comment: @Lundin I was thinking of using a PNP BJT because you remembered that UART RS485 communication idles HI.

Comment: @Alinik It's differential so it depends on which line you pick. Anyway, as mentioned you need a voltage larger than the forward voltage drop of the LED and I don't think the RS485 line guarantees as much, assuming you can get some 3V depending on LED color.

Comment: The schematic says Tx/Rx which would be the names of the UART signals inside the transceiver towards the MCU. The actual RS485 bus lines are called A or B, or T+/T- R+/R- in case of RS422 full duplex.

Comment: @Lundin With Tx/Rx for RS485 I meant A and B lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Your circuit with the BJT won't work.**  The RS485 voltage is likely to be 3.3V or 5V signal level.  But to turn off the transistor you probably need the signal to go as high as 22~23V (which it ordinarily won't).

**The circuit with the op amp can work, but not in all cases.**

- For a case with a 3.3V or 5V RS485 driver and no ground offset the LED will turn on/off.
- If there is ground offset of more than a few volts then the LED might not turn on/off.
- Strictly speaking the RS485 standard specifies that drivers provide 1.5V minimum output voltage.  A conforming driver that actually output 1.5V wouldn't provide enough voltage to turn the LED on/off.
- Over long distances it's possible that the signal level attenuates a lot.  The RS485 standard specifies that receivers detect signals as small as 200mV.  At 200mV your LED certainly won't turn on/off.

**Just connecting an LED, anti-parallel diode, and resistor directly to the RS485 lines can work, but not always.**

- For a case with a 3.3V or 5V driver and very little signal attenuation on the bus this will probably work.
- One downside is that the LED+resistor will present a load and affect the impedance on the bus.  It's probably fine for slower baud rates and shorter distances but could cause errors on longer distances or faster baud rates.
- Strictly speaking the RS485 standard specifies that drivers provide 1.5V minimum output voltage.  A conforming driver that actually output 1.5V wouldn't provide enough voltage to turn the LED on/off.
- Over long distances it's possible that the signal level attenuates a lot.  The RS485 standard specifies that receivers detect signals as small as 200mV.  At 200mV your LED certainly won't turn on/off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTbbfB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Probably the best way is to just connect the LED to the output of an RS485 transceiver chip.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0asa.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The last time I needed this I used a bi-directional LED with 100 ohms in series connected between A and B

No doubt that messed up the RS485 signal a littlem but didn't seem to hurt over desktop distances. A better approach would be to use an RS485 receiver chip to drive the LED.

Comment: Does this bi-directional LED connected between lines A and B of the RS485 mess up the signal on the bus both before and after the LED? I plan to insert it at the end of the bus anyway, so as not to dirty the signal for devices located downstream of the LED.